# Calcium carbonate and hydrochloric acid - data analysis

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism

I conducted an experiment in which $\pu{10mL}$ of dilute hydrochloric acid was added to a beaker, and this acid was heated up to room temperature ($\pu{22 ^\circ C}$) using a Bunsen burner. Then, $\pu{0.25 g}$ of calcium carbonate was then added to the beaker, and the time taken for it to dissolve (stop bubbling) was recorded. This was repeated at 3 other temperatures: $\pu{50^\circ C}$, $\pu{75^\circ C}$, and $\pu{100^\circ C}$.

Here is the graph with the results: 
[image]

So, my question is: why is there a 2-second difference between $\pu{50^\circ C}$ and $\pu{75^\circ C}$, and then a 6-second difference between $\pu{75^\circ C}$ and $\pu{100^\circ C}$? This is despite the temperature difference ($\pu{25^\circ C}$) staying the same - so why does the reaction rate change? I think this might have something to do with enzyme activity, but I am not sure.

And why is there such a drastic difference between $\pu{22^\circ C}$ and $\pu{50^\circ C}$, a whole 48 seconds? Yes, the temperature difference is $\pu{28^\circ C}$, not $\pu{25^\circ C}$, but that reduction is much more significant than at all the other temperatures. I think it might be something to do with the reactant concentration changing as the experiment progresses - again, I am not sure.

Any responses to this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Enzyme? Why are you mentioning enzyme activity

Comment: I am not sure either! I was searching the internet about this and that was all I could find.

Comment: This whole experiment makes IMO little sense. This is heterogeneous reaction - one might think it's simple, but it's virtually impossible to analyse without data you'd not think about. Even if you had almost identical monocrystals, kinetics depend on things like CO2 solubility, convection, nucleation sites for CO2...

Comment: @BlakedeRaat  Three replications per temperature are better than one, of course, but still are very very few, statistically speaking.  Equally, if you would have more data per temperature, an indication of estimated error / standard deviation would help to infer if changes in reaction time are significant, or not.  «Normal» spreadsheet programs sadly often do not provide this (keyword box-whisker plots, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot,  http://lithoguru.com/scientist/statistics/StatReview_Lecture2&3.xlsx) and if interested, you should venture out programs dedictated to this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have plotted your data as time(t) vs temperature(T) in kelvin and then fitted the plot with this equation:

$$ t = \frac{C}{e^{-F/T}}$$

where C and F are just parameters used for the fitting.

The Arrhenius equation gives the reaction rate relationship with temperature:
$$ k = \frac{d|P|}{dt} = Ae^{-Ea/(Kb*T)} $$

If you then integrate you can find the relationship between t(time) and temperature and this gives you an equation similar to the first one that I used to fit your data.

Actually, your data fits reasonably well with the model:

[image]

Comment: But what is the name of the first equation, the one with t =? I want to research a bit more about this. In particular, what is the name of the variable: −/? What is the C variable or constant called?

Comment: Also, how did you create this graph?

Comment: The equation with t doesn't have a name, I just derived it  from the differential  arrehnius equation but I inglobated more constants within the same letters C and F for the fitting.

Comment: I used origin and defined the first function (the one with t). The program varies the parameters C and F until it finds the best values that interpolate your experimental data. As you see this equation well interpolate your data suggest that the model is correct.

Comment: What is the program you used to model this?

Comment: The fact that 50 and 75 degrees have a similar time is within the experimental error.  The values more close to the predicted by theory should be read in the red fitted line. As you see temperature and time is not a linear relationship

Comment: Origin is the program